# C: How do I make my program reject words longer than 'y' or 'n'?

Tags: c, char, buffer, scanf

So the code below is a small part of a larger program, and by itself works just fine:

```
int main(){

char ansr;
scanf("%c", &ansr);


  while (ansr != 'y' && ansr != 'n'){

  printf("\n\tInvalid answer, Please try again.");
  while(getchar() != '\n');
  scanf("%c", &ansr);
}

if ( ansr == 'y') {
  sleep(1);
  printf("\n\tYou've been warned.......\n\n");
  sleep(3);
  }
else if ( ansr == 'n') {
  printf("\n\tGoodbye then.\n\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

as you can see, any word the user inputs that doesn't start with a y or n will be rejected until there is a right answer. How can I also include words that are longer than the characters 'y' and 'n', since as it is any character that starts with a y or n gives results for yes or no?

Comment: You should check that `scanf()` found a character, and that `getchar()` did not return EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such use cases, don't use `scanf` to read input. Use `fgets` to read the text line by line and process each line with whatever logic makes sense.

```
int main()
{
   char answer[LINE_LENGTH];  // #define LINE_LENGTH to a sensible value.
   while ( fgets(answer, LINE_LENGTH, stdin) != NULL )
   {
      // Trim the line of the newline character.
      int len = strlen(answer);
      if ( answer[len-1] == '\n' )
      {
         answer[len-1] = '\0';
      }

      if ( strcmp(answer, "y") == 0 ||
           strcmp(answer, "n") == 0 )
      {
         break;
      }

      printf("\n\tInvalid answer, Please try again.");
   }

   if ( strcmp(answer, "y") == 0)
   {
      sleep(1);
      printf("\n\tYou've been warned.......\n\n");
      sleep(3);
   }
   else if ( strcmp(answer, "n") == 0 )
   {
      printf("\n\tGoodbye then.\n\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Also, since the responses are one letter, a 3-byte char array would suffice (2 characters + null terminator). Then "eat up" characters on stdin with `fgetc(stdin)` until a newline or EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of getchar, to retrieve more than one character.